# Call a function from Test class not working Mockito

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, mockito

Hi I have a test class named UserServiceTest which contains userService class which is injected with the above mocks and the tests in this test class works fine.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class UserServiceTest {

lateinit var login: Login

@Mock
lateinit var userRepository: UserRepository

@Mock
lateinit var emailService: EmailService

@InjectMocks
lateinit var userService: UserService

@Before
fun setup() {
    login = Login(email = "mohanraj@gmail.com", password = "qwerty"
}
```

And I have another test class named AdminServiceTests which contains the AdminServiceClass which is injected with the above mocks which also consists the userService class

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class AdminServiceTests {

lateinit var user: User

@Mock
lateinit var userRepository: UserRepository

@Mock
lateinit var adminRepository: AdminRepository

@Mock
lateinit var userService: UserService

@InjectMocks
lateinit var adminService: AdminService

@Before
fun setup() {

    this.createAdmin = CreateAdmin().apply {
        email = "admin@gmail.com"
        name = "admin"
        password = "qwerty"
        phone = 98345678899
    }
}

@Test
fun testCreateAdmin() {

    val result = adminService.createAdmin(createAdmin)
    Assert.assertEquals(true, result)
}
```

When I run the test, adminService.createAdmin(createAdmin) calls a function in the adminService which calls a function in userService

```
fun createAdmin(newUser: CreateAdmin): Boolean {
    val user = userService.getUser(newUser)

    if (userService.createUser(user)) { // calls a function in user service
        this.saveAdmin(user.id)

        return true
    }

    return false
}
```

I want to call a function in userService from testCreateAdmin function, but the user service which I have included as @Mock contains some dependencies for itself and it is a dependency for adminService, so when I debug the @Mock userService object contains null and so the function in userService is not called. so how to inject the dependencies to userService and inject it into adminService.. Please help

```
userService = {UserService$MockitoMock$825690330@2479}
mockitoInterceptor = {MockMethodInterceptor@2532} 
userRepository = null
emailService = null
```

Comment: `UserService` is mocked in your `AdminServiceTests`, so it's original behavior is _replaced_ with whatever you configure (when this then that), or with default behavior if you did not specify anything, in your case `userService.createUser(user)` will return the default boolean value which is `false`. So yeah, it's normal that the original method is not invoked inside a mock, unless [you actually specify that](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.23.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#doCallRealMethod--), if that's actually what you really want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `testCreateAdmin()` you have to mock the behavior of the `userService` methods. By default, non-mocked methods will return `null`.

It should look like this, with mockito-kotlin.

```
@Test
fun testCreateAdmin() {
  val admin = mock<User>() {
    on { id } doReturn "id"
  }
  whenever(userService.getUser(createAdmin)).doReturn(admin)
  whenever(userService.createUser(admin)).doReturn(true)

  val result = adminService.createAdmin(createAdmin)

  Assert.assertEquals(true, result)
  verify(userService).saveAdmin("id")
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... Please help me with the question updated